# Audit data migration into Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, audit

I am having a task to migrate data from another database to Oracle database.

And data from previous database has audit information, i.e. tracking of create/update of records with update_time and update_user. For simplicity, let's assume the previous database I am talking about is an excel file of the following format:

```
Key | Value | Update_Time | Update_User |
----|-------|-------------|-------------|
a   | 1     | 23/04/2020  | user1       |
b   | 2     | 21/04/2020  | user2       |
a   | 3     | 20/04/2020  | user1       |
a   | 4     | 19/04/2020  | user5       |
a   | 5     | 18/04/2020  | user2       |
```

What is the best practice to move data into Oracle such that user can still query those audit info along with the new audit given that the data is now being saved to a new table in Oracle below? Does Oracle provide any native solution for this? I try Oracle Flashback, but not sure how to include those previous audit, because as I understand, we can only query Flashback for data change from now on. Ideally, I want to store only the latest data table in Oracle like this, as they are the actual active data:

```
Key | Value | Last_Update_Time | Last_Update_User |
----|-------|------------------|------------------|
a   | 1     | 23/04/2020       | user1            |
b   | 2     | 21/04/2020       | user2            |
```

Let's say user continue edit row with key `b` on 24/04/2020, then I want to fetch those result for UI display (currently I am using python sqlalchemy to access the db, but a solution with a sql query should be fine for the start)

```
Key | Value | Update_Time | Update_User |
----|-------|-------------|-------------|
b   | 7     | 24/04/2020  | user2       | ---> this is an update on the new oracle table above
a   | 1     | 23/04/2020  | user1       | ---> those rows below I want to somehow load into the oracle without explicitly create a new table for it
b   | 2     | 21/04/2020  | user2       |
a   | 3     | 20/04/2020  | user1       |
a   | 4     | 19/04/2020  | user5       |
a   | 5     | 18/04/2020  | user2       |
```

After the change, the main data table in Oracle should look below

```
Key | Value | Last_Update_Time | Last_Update_User |
----|-------|------------------|------------------|
a   | 1     | 23/04/2020       | user1            |
b   | 7     | 24/04/2020       | user2            |
```

Comment: So you need a oracle query?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. I am accessing the new oracle db with python sqlalchemy, but a solution with a sql query would be great for the start

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use the below select query

```
  SELECT AD.* FROM Audit_table AD, 
  (SELECT Key,Max(Update_time) Updated_Time,Last_updated_USer
  From Audit_table
  group by Key,Last_updated_USer)rec
  where AD.Key=rec.Key
  AND AD.Updated_Time=rec.Updated_Time
  AND AD.Last_updated_USer=rec.Last_updated_USer;
```

Comment: The point is that my audit table does not exist, I want to start setting it up that contains both previous audit from previous excel and audit from now now on. I can create an explicit audit table for this but it is like a last resort as I want a native solution from Oracle if any. Oracle Flashback (one solution I found) deals with the changes since the creation of the data table, but not the previous one in the old database (an excel in my example)

Comment: You can use a tool like sql loader to load the previous excel data in oracle db and then run this query

Comment: Other than the column _names_, I don't see any difference between your existing table to be imported, and your proposed new table.  So why don't you just import the old table and continue using it?  As for expecting Oracle to have a 'native' soluiton, these tables are obviously specific to your application, so  you can't expect oracle to know anything about how they are used or how any given 'old' table might relate to some proposed 'new' table.